# how to convert two data frame to one custom list file

Tags: r

I have two dataframes and I want to combine them in a list file 
my first dataframe is

```
 df1 <-structure(list(Countries = structure(c(4L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 
1L), .Label = c("Argentina", "Bangladesh", "Germany", "India", 
"Italy", "Spain", "USA"), class = "factor"), score = c(5L, 3L, 
3L, 36L, 27L, 38L, 42L), prescore = c(14L, 2L, 9L, 30L, 23L, 
28L, 30L), Here = c(1.654426641, 0.317580534, 1.198132543, 1.159607938, 
0.502336763, 0.258959426, 3.590781184), There = c(0.929521231, 
0.263531469, 0.856353826, 1.492219621, 0.446449268, 0.295339446, 
2.365211352), Thevalue = c(1.309899094, 0.165288467, 1.150147005, 
1.622165884, 0.528522213, 0.634062442, 1.733429701)), .Names = c("Countries", 
"score", "prescore", "Here", "There", "Thevalue"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

and the df2 in below

```
df2<-structure(list(Countries = structure(c(1L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 
2L), .Label = c("Brazil", "cuba", "holand", "Italy", "Spain", 
"UK", "USA"), class = "factor"), score = c(4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 28L, 
36L, 15L), prescore = c(1L, 25L, 9L, 24L, 65L, 27L, 31L), Here = c(1.654426641, 
0.317580534, 1.198132543, 1.159607938, 0.502336763, 0.258959426, 
3.590781184), There = c(0.929521231, 0.263531469, 0.856353826, 
1.492219621, 0.446449268, 0.295339446, 2.365211352), Thevalue = c(1.309899094, 
0.165288467, 1.150147005, 1.622165884, 0.528522213, 0.634062442, 
1.733429701)), .Names = c("Countries", "score", "prescore", "Here", 
"There", "Thevalue"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

I want to convert it to a list which looks like this

```
List of 2
 $ df1     :'data.frame':   7 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ countries  : chr [1:7] "India" "Bangladesh" "USA" "Germany" ...
  ..$ score      : int [1:7] 5 3 3 36  ...
  ..$ prescore   : int [1:7] 14 2 9 30 ...
  ..$ here       : num [1:7] 1.654 0.317 1.198 ...
  ..$ there      : num [1:7] 0.929 0.263 0.856 ...
  ..$ Thevalue   : num [1:7] 1.309 0.165 1.150 ...
 $ df2     :'data.frame':   7 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ countries  : chr [1:7] "Brazil" "holand" "USA" "UK" ...
  ..$ score      : int [1:7] 4 3 2 1  ...
  ..$ prescore   : int [1:7] 1 25 9 24  ...
  ..$ here       : num [1:7] 1.654 0.317 1.198 ...
  ..$ there      : num [1:7] 0.929 0.263 0.856 ...
  ..$ Thevalue   : num [1:7] 1.309 0.165 1.150 ...
```

Some people answer as list (df1,df2) but if i do that it will convert the first one as factor

look at here what I want

..$ countries  : chr [1:7] "Brazil" "holand" "USA" "UK" ...

Comment: @d.b if i do that then the first one will be factor

Comment: @d.b thanks that solved the problem , I appreciate it a lot , thanks for teaching me

Comment: @d.b just one thing. how to make that df1 and df2 appear in the list ? look at the output list df1 :'data.frame':

Comment: @d.b sorry to bother you but how to add this to the list(df1, df2)

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned in the comment above `list(df1, df2)` does the job. Sorry I overlooked the desired output. Proceed with the following

```
df1$Countries <- as.character(df1$Countries)
df2$Countries <- as.character(df2$Countries)
```

now

```
result <- list(df1, df2)
str(result)
```

should return the desired result

Comment: just one thing and i accept your answer. how to make that df1 and df2 appear in the list ? look at the output list df1     :'data.frame':

Comment: that is the output of `str()` command, I have updated the answer in response of your comment

Answer (score -1):

Consider casting each data frame as list inside the list() function:

```
df_list <- list(as.list(df1),as.list(df2))
df_list

[[1]]
[[1]]$Countries
[1] India      Bangladesh USA        Germany    Spain      Italy      Argentina 
Levels: Argentina Bangladesh Germany India Italy Spain USA

[[1]]$score
[1]  5  3  3 36 27 38 42

[[1]]$prescore
[1] 14  2  9 30 23 28 30

[[1]]$Here
[1] 1.65443 0.31758 1.19813 1.15961 0.50234 0.25896 3.59078

[[1]]$There
[1] 0.92952 0.26353 0.85635 1.49222 0.44645 0.29534 2.36521

[[1]]$Thevalue
[1] 1.30990 0.16529 1.15015 1.62217 0.52852 0.63406 1.73343


[[2]]
[[2]]$Countries
[1] Brazil holand USA    UK     Spain  Italy  cuba  
Levels: Brazil cuba holand Italy Spain UK USA

[[2]]$score
[1]  4  3  2  1 28 36 15

[[2]]$prescore
[1]  1 25  9 24 65 27 31

[[2]]$Here
[1] 1.65443 0.31758 1.19813 1.15961 0.50234 0.25896 3.59078

[[2]]$There
[1] 0.92952 0.26353 0.85635 1.49222 0.44645 0.29534 2.36521

[[2]]$Thevalue
[1] 1.30990 0.16529 1.15015 1.62217 0.52852 0.63406 1.73343
```

Comment: That is not the desired result.